How to enforce pylint validation before Firebase python function deploy
I'd like to run pylint and fail the firebase deploy if there are outstanding errors.
I can add pylint to my predeploy in firebase.json, but it doesn't seem to block the deployment on a non-zero return value.
      "predeploy": [
        "python3 -m venv functions_py/venv",
        ". functions_py/venv/bin/activate",
        "functions_py/venv/bin/python3 -m pip install -r functions_py/requirements.txt",
        "functions_py/venv/bin/pylint --ignore=venv functions_py"
      ]

What's the best way to enforce a zero return value for pylint before proceeding with a firebase functions deployment?

The open square bracket should be outside, not inside. Should be like this: ["predeploy":
